# C# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, json, linq, object

I have an string array

```
string[] a = ["a","b","c"];
```

I have a List (we'll call this "b") which I then deserialize into a string

```
[ {"name" : "a", "email": "b@c.com"}, {"name" : "a", "email": "b@c.com"} ]
```

I want to check if my List contains anything from string[] a.

```
var check = b.name.Contains(a[1]);
```

I get error

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

What other ways can I do this?

Comment: cast b.name to string before using contains should work

Answer (score 8):

Casting b.name.ToString() solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code too

```
var b= [{"name" : "a", "email": "b@c.com"}, {"name" : "a", "email": "b@c.com"}];

dynamic dy= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(b);

string res = dy["name"].toString();
```

Or

```
dy.name.ToString()
```